# Unable to locate message source for category 'mtrelt'

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

If I try to update records,I get following error without any ideas, what's about or what this error could have been caused by.
Furthermore, it's strange, that this error only will be bred by records having been imported by a dump. There will be no error, if I will update a record having been created using saveasnew option. Unfortunately, I can't delete this record in order to recreate it,'cause it would expel against referential integrity.
Here is error:

```
Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
Unable to locate message source for category 'mtrelt'.

throw new InvalidConfigException("Unable to locate message source for category '$category'.")

2. in ...\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\i18n\I18N.php at line 88 – yii\i18n\I18N::getMessageSource('mtrelt')
3. in ...\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php at line 509 – yii\i18n\I18N::translate('mtrelt', 'Data can't be deleted because it...', [], 'de-DE')

4. in ...\vendor\mootensai\yii2-relation-trait\RelationTrait.php at line 312 – yii\BaseYii::t('mtrelt', 'Data can't be deleted because it...')
```

Here is model:

```
<?php

namespace common\modules\lookup\models\base;

use Yii;
use mootensai\behaviors\UUIDBehavior;

class LPersonArt extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    use \mootensai\relation\RelationTrait;


    public function relationNames()
    {
        return [
            'eAppEinstellungArts',
            'lKontaktVerwendungszwecks',
            'people'
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['person_art'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['zieltabelle'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['bemerkung'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
        ];
    }

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'l_person_art';
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'person_art' => Yii::t('app', 'Personengruppen'),
            'zieltabelle' => Yii::t('app', 'Zieltabelle'),
            'bemerkung' => Yii::t('app', 'Bemerkung'),
        ];
    }


    public function getEAppEinstellungArts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\common\modules\erweiterung\models\EAppEinstellungArt::className(), ['id_person_art' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getLKontaktVerwendungszwecks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\common\modules\lookup\models\LKontaktVerwendungszweck::className(), ['id_person_art' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getPeople()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\common\modules\basis\models\Person::className(), ['id_person_art' => 'id']);
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'uuid' => [
                'class' => UUIDBehavior::className(),
                'column' => 'id',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public static function find()
    {
        return new \common\modules\lookup\models\LPersonArtQuery(get_called_class());
    }
}
```

Here is Controller:

```
  public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = new LPersonArt();
        if (!Yii::$app->request->post('_asnew') == '1'){       
            $model = $this->findModel($id);
        }
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->saveAll()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Here is view:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<div class="lperson-art-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'id', ['template' => '{input}'])->textInput(['style' => 'display:none']); ?>

    <?=
    $form->field($model, 'person_art')->widget(\jlorente\remainingcharacters\RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
        'type' => \jlorente\remainingcharacters\RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXTAREA,
        'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
        'options' => [
            'rows' => '3',
            'class' => 'col-md-12',
            'maxlength' => 50,
            'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Write something')
        ]
    ])
    ?>

    <?=
    $form->field($model, 'bemerkung')->widget(\jlorente\remainingcharacters\RemainingCharacters::classname(), [
        'type' => \jlorente\remainingcharacters\RemainingCharacters::INPUT_TEXTAREA,
        'text' => Yii::t('app', '{n} characters remaining'),
        'options' => [
            'rows' => '3',
            'class' => 'col-md-12',
            'maxlength' => 255,
            'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Write something')
        ]
    ])
    ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id != 'save-as-new'): ?>
            <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id != 'create'): ?>
            <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save As New'), ['class' => 'btn btn-info', 'value' => '1', 'name' => '_asnew']) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Cancel'), Yii::$app->request->referrer, ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Had you created message file app.po?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem will be solved adding following code into components of

```
common/config/main-local.php
```

```html
      'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                '*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => '@backend/messages', // if advanced application, set @frontend/messages
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'de',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, but the Yii2 error message was

> Unable to locate message source for category ''

I was running Gii from console:

```
php yii gii/crud --controllerClass="app\controllers\StcDocumentTypeController" --messageCategory="stc_document_type" --enableI18N=1 --enablePjax=1  --interactive=0 --modelClass="app\models\StcDocumentType" --searchModelClass="app\models\StcDocumentTypeSearch"  --overwrite=1
```

The solution was to add the **i18n** configuration on the console.php config file:

```
'components' => [
...
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [
        '*' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            'basePath' => '@app/messages',
            'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
        ],
    ]
],
...
```

]

If you're running from web check also that config in web.php